# Netflix, Amazon Video and youtube intermittent streaming errors

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, connection, network-adapter

my PC has issues streaming from Netflix, Amazon and Youtube (my laptop and FireStick work fine).

When streaming the video will play fine (buffers fine etc.) but then will randomly cut out, maybe as often as 10-15 times in an hour. I get an `M7361-1253` error from Netflix and iirc no error code from the others.

So far I've:

- tried different Ethernet ports, tried with on-board WiFi (with multiple channels).
- reinstalled and checked for updates on my network devices, my motherboard etc.
- restarted everything in the chain more times than I can count.
- contacted Netflix. They said that when they checked my connection there were a 'couple of red flags' in that the speeds were unstable; constantly average at 25Mbs down but will regularly 'jump' up and down (for a moment) apparently to the point it causes an error with the stream, though I've only recorded it 'drop' to 10-15Mbs during speed tests which doesn't seem low enough to break anything.
- contacted my ISP ('everything looks fine')

Because I don't seem to be having the same problem elsewhere I feel it might actually not be the ISP's fault (as alien a concept as everything *ever* not being the fault of my ISP is to me).

Sadly I'm completely out of ideas.

---

**Addendum:**
Possibly related: last weekend (before I spent any time watching videos) I kept desyncing while playing a couple different online games.

So this has been a problem with my PC for a week, ever since I reformatted it.
Before that I hadn't really used it much, but I was 'having issues' with it running dog slow to a point where I probably didn't use it enough since before Christmas some time to judge if I was having this issue. (the 'game issues' felt consistent but given it would often take 5 minutes to respond to opening a program I'm not willing to draw a correlation with the current problem yet)

Any suggestions for where the problem might lie, what to try next, or just any suggestions on how I could diagnose this would be Greatly Appreciated.

OS: Windows 7 Pro N 64bit (SP1)
MB: Asus P8Z77-V Delux
CPU: i7 3770k 3.5GHz

Comment: Pretty much all sounds like a flaky connection with your isp

Comment: I guess so, and it working fine on other devices could be them handling the intermittent failures better?

Comment: Any correlation with time of day? Are there other high-bandwidth users in your household? Is your CPU at max during the stutters (unlikely with an i7)? Or is the browser process occupying a full CPU core? Do the problems occur with both flash and HTML5?

Comment: Are you on cable or adsl? If cable, does your modem have detailed downstream channel frequencies? Power fluctuations at the exchange can cause the higher-frequency ones to be intermittent; easy to escalate this to the ISP if you can screenshot it in modem settings.

Comment: Have you performed basic maintenance on the PC? Check for malware, removed unused browser extensions/add-ons, or software.

Comment: I'd expect ISP problems outside the house to give rise to problems with the other devices (laptop, amazon fire)?

Comment: @RJFalconer No other users on the network, and it happens even when my PC is the only thing connected.

My CPU, Memory, Network and Disk Usage don't seem to spike when it happens (and are not even remotely close to max at the time).

It happens both on flash and HTML5, but I checked and it doesn't happen when I run from a 'Linux Live' Usb.

Comment: @RJFalconer I'm on Fibre cable... and don't know much (/anything) about downstream channel frequencies or how I' check them.

I'll look into that after work I guess.

Comment: @bbatman I've checked for malware and random browser addons and such, fortunately it was a short list because of the recent format.